# Using C# IComparer in Unity game engine

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am writing an Edge class for my graph for an A* implementation. I would want to later create a list of Edges and sort them based on edge weights using the IComparer interface.

Below is my implementation of Edge class inside Unity 4.5f

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Edge : IComparer {

    Node destination;
    int weight;

    public Edge(Node destinationNode, int cost)
    {
        destination = destinationNode;
        weight = cost;
    }

    public Node getDestination()
    {
        return destination;
    }

    public int getCost()
    {
        return weight;
    }

    int IComparer.Compare(System.Object a, System.Object b)
    {
        if (((Edge)a).getCost() == ((Edge)b).getCost()) return 0;
        else if (((Edge)a).getCost() > ((Edge)b).getCost()) return 1;
        else return -1;
    }
}
```

But Unity throws the below error

> ArgumentException: does not implement right interface
>   System.Collections.Generic.Comparer`1+DefaultComparer[Edge].Compare
>   (.Edge x, .Edge y) (at
>   /Users/builduser/buildslave/mono-runtime-and-classlibs/build/mcs/class/corlib/System.Collections.Generic/Comparer.cs:86)

I also tried using `IComparer<Edge>` but it throws error

> The non generic type 'System.Collections.IComparer' cannot be used
>   with type arguments

Unity also does not allow me to use IComparable as it does not understand when I try to use it :( it throws

> " type or namespace not found "

I don't know whats wrong. Could someone please help me out?

Comment: Try implementing the generic interface instead `IComparer<Edge>` as the error implies it is looking for that interface: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8ehhxeaf.aspx 
You could also consider inheriting from Comparer<Edge> instead

Comment: What version of Unity?

Comment: Unity 4.5

I tried using IComparer<Edge>. It throws error. Please read my first post, I have updated the question

Comment: Did you try using System.Collections.Generic instead of System.Collections?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think Unity expects you to implement `IComparable<Edge>` (generic version of IComparable, please see http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/4d7sx9hd%28v=vs.110%29.aspx )

This implementation will be really close to yours, except it doesn't need casts (since input types are already some Edge)

Comment: Unity does not allow me to use IComparable as in it does not understand what IComparable is which is why I used IComparer :(

Comment: Yes, IComparable<Edge>, not IComparer<Edge>

Comment: According the exception you meet, it looks like you still don't implement the right interface. I think you typed "IComparer" rather than "IComparable" ;)

Comment: When I use IComparable it says " type or namespace not found " lol

Comment: Do you have include System namespace ? "using System;"

Comment: Okay I guess that fixed that problem. let me see if it works now. Thanks!!